# Trying to configure metrics.net in asp net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, metrics

I have a asp.net core web application, and i want to use metrics.net.

before, i configure metrics and owin like this:

```c#
Metric.Config
            .WithInternalMetrics()
            .WithOwin(middleware => app.Use(middleware), config => config
                .WithRequestMetricsConfig(c => c.WithErrorsMeter()
                                                .WithActiveRequestCounter()
                                                .WithPostAndPutRequestSizeHistogram()
                                                .WithRequestTimer()
                                            , new[] {
                                                    new Regex("(?i)^metrics"),
                                                    new Regex("(?i)^health"),
                                                    new Regex("(?i)^json")
                                                    }
                                            )
                .WithMetricsEndpoint(endpointConfig =>
                {
                    endpointConfig
                        .MetricsTextEndpoint(enabled: false);                            
                })
            );
```

how can i do some similar in asp net core?

Comment: Metric.net doesn't support dotnet core yet. You could use it only with full framework. Look here [docs.asp.net](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/owin.html). [GitHub issue](https://github.com/etishor/Metrics.NET/issues/133)

Comment: @Kalten : You can have ASP.NET Core running on (standard) .NET Framework. Using Johan's answer I was able to successfully configure the OWIN adapter for Metrics.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to use `app.UseOwin` from `Microsoft.AspnetCore.Owin` package and connect the right middleware to the pipeline.

```cs
Metric.Config.WithInternalMetrics()
            .WithOwin(middleware => app.UseOwin(pipeline => pipeline(next => Engage(middleware, next))), config => config
                .WithRequestMetricsConfig(c => c.WithAllOwinMetrics()
                                            , new[] {
                                                    new Regex("(?i)^metrics"),
                                                    new Regex("(?i)^health"),
                                                    new Regex("(?i)^json")
                                                    }
                                            )
                .WithMetricsEndpoint(endpointConfig =>
                {
                    endpointConfig
                        .MetricsJsonEndpoint(enabled: true)
                        .MetricsEndpoint(enabled: true)
                        .MetricsHealthEndpoint(enabled: true)
                        .MetricsTextEndpoint(enabled: false)
                        .MetricsPingEndpoint(enabled: false);
                })
            );
```

and the Engage function like this

```cs
  private static Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task> Engage(dynamic middleware, Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task> next)
    {
        return env => {
            middleware.Initialize(next);

            return middleware.Invoke(env);
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [.NET Standard port](https://github.com/alhardy/AppMetrics) of Metrics.NET. The API into metrics has be re-written following the .net core approach